# Empty array when looping json array in Nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, adonis.js

I want to get specific data from JSON array in adonisjs. But I have some problem to get that data. When I'm looping this JSON array the return just only **empty** array = []. This is my controller code:

```
   const detail= await TrxHistory.query()
        .where('id_trx', params.id_trx)
        .fetch()
```

This return json array:

```
[
    {
        "id_trx_history": "1",
        "id_trx": "3",
        "trx_status": "shop_confirm",
        "created_at": "2019-10-18 22:27:54"
    },
    {
        "id_trx_history": "1",
        "id_trx": "3",
        "trx_status": "shop_process",
        "created_at": "2019-10-18 22:29:48"
    },
]
```

And i'm try to get data from row "trx_status", using looping like this:

```
        let data = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
            data[i] = detail[i]["trx_status"];
        }
        console.log(data);
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you try this : `detail.rows.length` & `detail.rows[i]["..."]`

Comment: @CrBast the return is ```"Cannot read property 'transaction_status' of undefined"``` what's wrong?

Comment: What is the result of  `detail.rows`?

Comment: try to write `console.log(detail)` and show, please, an output?

Comment: i'm try ```detail.rows.length & detail.rows[i]["..."]``` but the return is **unexpected token**, then using ```detail.rows``` the return still empty array

Comment: @StepUp the result is 204 no content :( or the return only empty array

Comment: @isnainibarochatun so it looks like you are not getting data, so this is a reason why you have an empty array

Comment: thank you @CrBast and @StepUp finally i knew.. i have to change with ```detail.rows.length & detail.rows[i]["..."]``` and just now, i'm fixing my code because i made some mistakes when writing rows name :( thank you so much it work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `fetch` adonis lucid request you need to use `.rows`. Like:

```js
... // Your query

let fooData = [];
detail.rows.forEach(de => {
    fooData.push(el.trx_status)
})
```

#### How to use?

```
detail.rows[1]
detail.rows.length
```

Answer (score 0):

If `detail` has a structure that you've shown, then it should work perfectly:

```js
const detail = [
{
    "id_trx_history": "1",
    "id_trx": "3",
    "trx_status": "shop_confirm",
    "created_at": "2019-10-18 22:27:54"
},
{
    "id_trx_history": "1",
    "id_trx": "3",
    "trx_status": "shop_process",
    "created_at": "2019-10-18 22:29:48"
},
];

let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
     data[i] = detail[i]["trx_status"];
}
console.log(data);

// another way:
let fooData = [];
detail.forEach(el => {
    el["trx_status"] ? fooData.push(el["trx_status"]) : null;
});
console.log(fooData);
```